# CKEditor -- Use Custom Style Sheet with Editor

Tags: ckeditor

I have been trying to work out how to get my own website's custom stylesheet to be recognized by CKEditor. The fontsize on my site is 19px, and for CKEditor it's much smaller. I would like the software to recognize my styles. I don't need (at the moment) custom styles added to dropdowns (and I see information in the docs on how to do that). It just seems odd that if my whole site uses a specific font, font size, font color, and so on that the editor doesn't seem to recognize them. This may be basic, and I've just looked past it or misunderstood something, but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the contents.css (file is inside CKEditor folder), that is the stylesheet used for content inside the CKEditor. You will need to change the contents.css according to your need, in this case you want to change the font styling so it match with your current site.